# Replace wget 1.20.3 provided by Linux Mint 20.3 with the version 1.21.2 compiled by myself

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

For unknown reasons, the `wget` version provided by Linux Mint 20.3 gave me a segmentation fault error.

That's why I replaced it with the last version:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
tar -xf wget-latest.tar.gz
cd wget-1.21.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The last step (`sudo make install`) has overwritten the version of `wget` that came with Linux Mint. I cannot remove the deb package `wget` because of dependencies with Cinnamon.

Future OS updates may overwrite the version of wget compiled by me.

What do I do in such cases?

I tag the question with "Linux Mint" and "Ubuntu" because the problem is similar. In fact, not only Cinnamon depends on the `wget` package, but also Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have specified a prefix like "/usr/local" with ./configure, and put /usr/local/bin first in your PATH.